# Change in Ajax between VS2005 and VS2010

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2010

I've never used AJAX before. I'm new to web design but I have a website that I need to add certain dynamic functionality to. Ajax seems like it would help. Problem is, most of the Ajax articles relate to VS2005. I'm using VS2010 Premium Edition. There must have been lots of changes between the versions. I don't have any Ajax toolbox tabs. I didn't even have a timer control available in the toolbox - I have now added one from the System.Web.Extensions Assembly.

Does anyone have info on what's happened to Ajax in VS2010?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX hasn't changed in all that time.  AJAX toolkits have been introduced, though.  You should look into what is available.  Particularly, I would look at ASP.Net AJAX (along with the AJAXControlToolkit), and JQuery.